# Save ArrayList to file - FC when creating ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, android, file, caching

I'm trying to implement some simple caching into my application and I'm having some issues.

Basically my code scrapes a webpage, gets some regex matches and puts them into an ArrayList. This takes a while to do (a few seconds, but this happens frequently) so I'm trying to implement a simple caching system which checks when the cache file was modified, if this is older than a week, refresh cache.

My problem lies with storing the ArrayList, can anyone help with this?

I originally have (which works)

```
  private List<String> getVideoIDS(final String url2) {

        if (android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  //android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(),"PL" + url.getQuery());
        else
            cacheDir=mContext.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

        File f = new File(cacheDir, "PL"+url.getQuery());

        if (f.lastModified() > 604800000 || f.exists() == false) { 
        String expr = "(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]{11}|(?<=v=)[^&\n]{11}";

        int count = 0;   
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(expr,
                  Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNIX_LINES | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                try {
                    url = new URL(url2);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    m = patt.matcher(getURLContent(url));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (m.find()) {
                    if ("default.jpg".equals(m.group(0)) || "videos?view".equals(m.group(0))) {
                        //Do nothing
                        } else { 
                            allMatches.add(m.group(0));
                            count++;
                            Log.i("", m.group(0));
                }
                }

                //Remove duplicates
                List<String> noDupes = new ArrayList<String>();
                Iterator iterator = allMatches.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    String o = (String) iterator.next();
                    if(!noDupes.contains(o)) noDupes.add(o);
                }

        allMatches = noDupes;   
                return allMatches; }
```

Now what I'm trying to modify this to be is this (in theory, as it currently doesn't work)

```
  private List<String> getVideoIDS(final String url2) {

        if (android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  //android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory(),"PL" + url.getQuery());
        else
            cacheDir=mContext.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

        File f = new File(cacheDir, "PL"+url.getQuery());

        if (f.lastModified() > 604800000 || f.exists() == false) { 
        String expr = "(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]{11}|(?<=v=)[^&\n]{11}";

        int count = 0;   
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(expr,
                  Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.UNIX_LINES | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                try {
                    url = new URL(url2);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    m = patt.matcher(getURLContent(url));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (m.find()) {
                    if ("default.jpg".equals(m.group(0)) || "videos?view".equals(m.group(0))) {
                        //Do nothing
                        } else { 
                            allMatches.add(m.group(0));
                            count++;
                            Log.i("", m.group(0));
                }
                }

                //Remove duplicates
                List<String> noDupes = new ArrayList<String>();
                Iterator iterator = allMatches.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    String o = (String) iterator.next();
                    if(!noDupes.contains(o)) noDupes.add(o);
                }

        allMatches = noDupes;       


        ObjectOutputStream save = null;

        FileOutputStream saveFile = null;
        try {
            saveFile = new FileOutputStream(cacheDir + "PL"+url.getQuery());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create an ObjectOutputStream to put objects into save file.
        try {
            save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            save.writeObject(allMatches);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            save.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allMatches;}

        else {
              try{  
                   // Open file to read from, named SavedObjects.sav.
                   FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream(cacheDir + "PL"+url.getQuery());

                   // Create an ObjectInputStream to get objects from save file.
                   final ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);

                   // Now we do the restore.
                   // readObject() returns a generic Object, we cast those back
                   // into their original class type.
                   // For primitive types, use the corresponding reference class.
                   allMatches = (ArrayList) save.readObject();
                   // Close the file.
                   save.close();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    // This also closes saveFile.

              }
        } return allMatches; 
}
```

Note: I'm trying to save multiple files as this method is called for various different categories. That should be handled with calling the file a different filename based on whats open. I think I have implemented this correctly.

Stacktrace is as follows

```
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.VideoGrid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeShort(DataOutputStream.java:192)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeStreamHeader(ObjectOutputStream.java:1815)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:279)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.test.test.VideoGrid.getVideoIDS(VideoGrid.java:204)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.test.test.VideoGrid.onCreate(VideoGrid.java:74)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4524)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
04-03 17:41:20.846: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
```

This

```
com.test.test.VideoGrid.getVideoIDS(VideoGrid.java:204)
```

Points to

```
save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
```

I have 
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

In my manifest

I have tried changing the filename to something static (1) instead of my url.getQuery incase that was the problem - doesn't change anything, exact same problem.

I feel I'm making a fundamental error here. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with saving/reading the ArrayList?

Comment: Post the log statements when the crash occurs

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP my logcat isn't working properly. It provides me with a NullPointerException from another project entirely. This happens all the time when I copy a project. However, when this project is working properly there is no error regarding that other project. As I have no idea why this happens or how to fix it I was hoping somebody could see an obvious mistake I may have made

Comment: Yes, I found the obvious mistake: posting to SO *without* a focused question and *without* even useful exception/debugging information. Try a "code review" site if you want another pair of eyes. :-) Basically, if the *question* cannot be adequately summed up in the title, it does not belong here.

Comment: Do Project -> Clean (if you are using eclipse). That helps in scenarios like this one.

Comment: Pst - I think I have adequately described my problem, I also explained why I was unable to provide a stack trace. Raunuk, thanks for the suggestions, I've tried that. It hasn't worked. Always seems to happen when I duplicate a project to test code

Comment: crash log must be paste,will be useful

Comment: My OP has been updated to reflect the stacktrack. (to fix my DDMS problem I copied my broken code into my original, working project)

Comment: On the line that throws the exception, what is `url` and what does `url.getQuery()` return?  I suggest you log the value of both right before that line.

Comment: Ah, my url wasn't being passed correctly. Thanks. Unfortunately it breaks just a few lines below now instead when writing the object. I'm updating my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your save file wasn't found; but its hard to tell since your code is currently  swallowing all of the exceptions. instead of :

```
try {
    saveFile = new FileOutputStream(cacheDir + "PL"+url.getQuery())
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Try logging your exceptions instead, since e.printStackTrace(); doesn't do anything by default on android.

```
catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {
  Log.e(getClass().getName(), "File not found:" + cacheDir + "PL" + url.getQuery()", e1);
}
```

Anyway, that's my theory - your file path is pointing to somewhere that can't be written to for whatever reason (the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29) have some possible explanations); saveFile then comes out of the exception as null, and then you pass the null parameter into the outputStream constructor

Comment: Thank you. This now results in '04-04 20:36:05.958: E/com.test.test.VideoGrid(3777): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/PLPL8F5A29F57DB58FCB: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'. I can find little about this problem on the internet, it doesn't appear to be an actual permissions error (I have tried all the relevant ones)

Comment: @CitizenSmif Is there a reason you're using `getDataDirectory()` instead of `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

Comment: It turns out there was a couple different things wrong, it was mainly mainly me using the wrong filename and the error was being produced because I was trying to write to external storage incorrectly. Your answer led me to fixing this. Thanks v much JR